# Example where photon acts only as a wave

Tags: photons, wave-particle-duality

I've heard photon can act both as a wave and as a particle. In the photoelectric effect it acts as a particle.

Is there any example where photon acts only as a wave?

Comment: Good question, albeit when you speak *photons*, you have come out of the wave nature on purpose.

Comment: If you look for an example where the "particle" nature of the electromagnetic radiation is completely invisible, you can always look at radio waves.

Comment: @fraxinus oh are x rays an example too? i am pretty sure they dont have particles flowing through but how do those xrays and radiowaves transmit. its not like the usual transverse wave right or is it?

Comment: @ChristinaMelita X-rays behave as particles when you make an x-ray image of your bones (they either pass thru or collide with some other particle) and as a wave (they difract and interfere between the atoms) when used in x-ray crystalography. So no, not a good example.

Comment: oh ok but radio waves never act like particle.

Comment: @ChristinaMelita You might want to consider the maser, a quantum radio device. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maser

Comment: thanks @JohnDoty

Comment: @ChristinaMelita - and radio waves do diffract off of buildings and earth features (e.g. mountains), which impact radio propagation.

Comment: question is itself wrong. A photon is a particle which Einstein referred as light quanta. When you talk of photon you are only talking of the particle side.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a misconception in the question, a photon by axiomatic definition in the [standard model of particle physics,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) where it is defined in the table **is always a point particle,** and its kinematics is tied up with [quantum mechanics.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) In quantum mechanics it is the **wave function**  $Ψ$  whose complex conjugate form $Ψ^*Ψ$ is equal to the probability of seeing a photon at (x,y,z) at time t.

[See here](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) how single photons added up with the same boundary conditions end up giving **distributions**  that show the interference patterns associated with light, electromagnetic waves.

[image: dblslphot]

> 1. Single-photon camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames.

The dots are the individual footprints of photons, and a **single photon is never a wave**, as it is a point particle. It can be shown mathematically that the classical electromagnetic field with the light waves emerges from the quantum mechanical level of photons, but it needs quantum field theory to follow the proof [(example](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) ).

Comment: I'm happy that you specified that you are confining your remarks to the standard model.  In other contexts the wave nature is more appropriate.

Comment: $\Psi^*\Psi$ is **not** the probability of seeing a photon at (x,y,z) at time t. There is no meaningful notion of wavefunction for photons.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  sorry but that is your opinion .see http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en .  Everything emerges from  basic quantum mechanics, imo.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The example you have given is proof that single photons have got wave properties.  Interference is a wave property.  If "single photon is never a wave" was true, there would be no interference pattern.  The interference pattern you have shown is a repeated single particle measurement, not a many-particle measurement.  See the correct answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/638631/62146.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist your logic evades me. Th question is about **a photon**, not an **ensembe of photons**, and my answer shows an accumulation of single photons. I also give a link to how an **ensemble of photons** is shown mathematically to give rise to electromagnetic fields.

Comment: "and my answer shows an accumulation of single photons"  Yes, and they form an interference pattern, so they have wave properties.  It's unambiguous.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist its is unambiguous for the ensemble, not for the individual photon which leaves an experimental foot print of a point, as the standard model axiomatically assumes.

Comment: The picture you posted is not an ensemble measurement.  It is a sum of multiple single particle measurements.  You even acknowledged that in your comment above.  I won't discuss this further.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Yes individual photons even have color ... and that's a pretty fundamental wave property.

Comment: @anna the paper http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en says the photon is non-local so no wave function of x,y,z  only p ....

Comment: @PhysicsDave  for some reason I cannot access the document server . is it the same paper as this https://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/0604/0604169.pdf ? The  function in formula 9 " is  the  probability density for energy, not particle location " . What the exeriment shows *is* the probability density in space, which is localized in the region of molecules interacting with the photon.  The energy wave-packet interacts like a particle, experimentally as seen above.

Comment: @PhysicsDave  as far as color, one *derives* the color from  E=hν , one does not "see it" unless  there is the accumulation shown . The individual photon leaves a dot.

Comment: Yes that is the paper. At issue is “from Ψ Ψ* is equal to the probability of seeing a photon at (x,y,z) at time t.”  Since the photon is non-local Ψ Ψ* is  the energy of the photon within a certain volume, i.e. if the photon(s) was traveling 1 meter from source to sensor the energy density would be 10% for the first 10 cm of path and 10% again and so on for the remaining 10 cm segments.  I think we cannot use the word “seeing”  because the photon wave function just says the photon is everywhere until it is observed.

Comment: Furthermore a single photon or a photon flux is full of shot noise, i.e we cannot say exactly when the single photon will emit and in a flux of photons we can only be certain of that the flux is 7 photons or 13 (1 sigma) for an intended 10 photon flux at any given point in time.

Comment: But the most important point is that even a single photon has wave properties! The photons pictured above have acted individually ... they could be fired once per year for a 1000 years and we still get the "interference" pattern.  They never go in the dark areas .... Feynman path integral is a decent starting explanation for this.

Comment: @PhysicsDave No explanation except the axiomatic wavefunction  Ψ Ψ*  which is part of the postulates of quantum mechanics http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html .   *it  a probability wave nature*

Comment: @annav A single electron also has proven wave properties.

Comment: @PhysicsDave yes, as is shown above, **probability wave**  as seen in the double slit here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles  .  In the particle physics standard model, mainstream one, the electron is a point particle, and experimentally an electron leaves a footpring of a particle, no spread in space.

Comment: Bach’s team reduced the intensity of the incident beam so that only one electron was detected each second, thereby guaranteeing (to greater than 99.9999% probability) that only a single electron was present between the source and the detector at any time. The experiment ran continuously for two hours and, initially, the individual electrons appeared to arrive at random points on the screen. But as more and more electrons were detected, an interference pattern with bright and dark regions gradually emerged (2013 New J. Phys. 15 033018). https://physicsworld.com/a/double-slits-with-single-atoms/

Comment: @Anna I would like to see your comment on the above. Admittedly in this case it is not photons, but electrons. My comment refers to Bach's experiment. I didn't have enough characters left to put your name in front.

Comment: All quantum mechanical entities can  have probability wave interference , and this is what the experiment shows. To see the interference an ensemble from the same type of atoms is necessary , but they explain the mathematics with how a single atom res[ponds to the two radiations falling on it.

Comment: @Anna It seems you finally agree with me. But I don't know exactly what you mean by a single atom responding to 2 radiations. It seems to me that the reference to single atoms in the heading of the article I sent you is a mistake. What is meant are electrons of photons, I wonder if you would dare comment on Deutsch's assertion that the single photon interacts with another from another world. It is ridiculous to me. We daren't even mention it on this website. He doesn't believe in particle-wave duality.

Answer (score 21):

It is not true to say that a photon acts in some circumstances as a classical particle and in other circumstances as a classical wave. Rather, it acts in all circumstances like a quantum thing, which is *neither* a classical point particle *nor* a classical wave. Having said that, some of the behaviours are reminiscent of classical particles and others are reminiscent of classical waves, and it is good to draw attention to this.

The most direct way to see where the wavelike behaviours arise is to examine interference phenenomena, where each photon has more than one route from a source to a detector. The Young's slits experiment is the standard example. One finds there is a pattern of bright and dark fringes; this pattern is in the probability of arrival of the photons at one place or another. This pattern corresponds precisely to the classical wave optics prediction for such experiments.

A stream of photons will exhibit behaviours that match the classical wave optics most fully when there are many photons and one looks at statistical averages. The classical monochromatic wave, for example, corresponds to a collection of photons with frequencies distributed close to some given frequency, and such that the number of photons is in a superposition state described statistically by a poissonian distribution. Such a state is called a *coherent state* of the electromagnetic field.

Comment: thanks for answering. in youngs slit experiment will the photons have particle behaviour too or is it a full wave behaviour?

Comment: @ChristinaMelita that depends on how they are detected. The most common way is a detection method based on energy deposited in either an electronic CCD element or a chemical reaction in a photographic film. In this case it is found that the energy arrives in lumps. Each lump all arrives at a single spot; this corresponds to one photon. The fact that each lump of energy arrives all in one place is an example of particle-like behaviour. The wave-like behaviour remains in the probability distribution of where these lumps arrive, as I said above.

Comment: Your first paragraph made me think: [A photon is like this set of equations, for which any analogy must be an approximation](https://xkcd.com/895/)

Answer (score 3):

Interference and diffraction are phenomena where photon exhibits its wave nature purely. Polarization is another phenomenon, where photons act exclusively as waves.

Comment: No, a photon does not interfere and never acts as a wave.

Comment: @my2cts When you say "a photon does not interfere", (1) how do you account for the fact that in a Young's slits experiment no photons arrive at the dark fringes (and this is so even when there is at most one photon in the apparatus at any one time)? (2) what is a path integral (as in Feynman diagrams etc.) if not a superposition (i.e. interference) of amplitudes associated with many paths?

Comment: You could ask this as a new question, to avoid extensive discussion here. I can already say, no problem.

Comment: @my2cts All particles are always waves. That's how quantum physics works.

Comment: @nick012000 This is an untenable position.

Answer (score 3):

Individual photons are fundamental particles, and act as particles, although they behave as quantum particles, not as classical/ macroscopic particles.

A population of many photons with the same energy/frequency/wavelength can be treated as if it is a classical wave - this allows the classical analysis of phenomena such as polarisation, refraction and reflection.

Comment: @physicsdave That is what I thought. It is funny that people have a problem with single particle interference. Especially David Deutsch.

Answer (score 2):

A photon, just like an electron, a proton or a molecule is a particle. Its behavior is however statistical, also just like that of an electron, a proton or a molecule. This statistical behavior is described by a wave function. In the case of photons this is the electromagnetic potential. It is this potential or its derivative the electromagnetic field that exhibits the wave behavior including interference. Photons themselves do not exhibit interference nor wave behaviour. They do not have a frequency or a wavelength, unlike their wave function, but they do have energy and momentum.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to describe the wave-particle duality is to note three things.

First, a "photon" (or any quantum object) behaves like a photon. The labels "wave" and "particle" are given by experimenters but the photon isn't bound by names.

Second, a "photon" behaves like a particle in an experiment designed to measure particle-like properties.

Third, (really part 2-A) a "photon" behaves like a wave in an experiment designed to measure wave-like properties.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice answer by @annav, I would like to add something the other answer do not mention, that is the example of Rayleigh scattering.

> Rayleigh scattering (/ˈreɪli/ RAY-lee), named after the nineteenth-century British physicist Lord Rayleigh (John William Strutt),[1] is the predominantly elastic scattering of light or other electromagnetic radiation by particles much smaller than the wavelength of the radiation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering

Individual photons are quantum objects (and they are defined in the SM as point particles), though, they do build up the classical EM waves that travel from the Sun and scatter on the atoms in our atmosphere. These light waves have a wavelength that is much bigger then the atoms in the atmosphere, but the scattering process itself is wavelength dependent. Blue light has higher frequency and shorter wavelength, thus, those photons of higher energy (blue) scatter with higher probability. This is a beautiful example of how light's wave properties dominate throughout the scattering process and create the colors of our skies.

Your question is about individual photons, and though these are quantum objects, that are defined as point particles in the SM, when they beautifully build up the classical EM waves, and scatter on the atoms in the atmosphere, the wave properties manifest and the wavelength dependency of the process emerges from the fundamental (quantum) properties of the universe.